# eval(string) as a line of executable code for ms access

Tags: eval

I am having trouble getting the EVAL function to evaluate a string as a line of executable code.  I can’t find much online about using it for that purpose. (Maybe because it can’t be done?).

```
Public Function UpdateControlBackground (frobnitz as String)
    Eval(frobnitz)
End of Function
```

Where `frobnitz` is the string `“ Forms!Main." & rs!NameOfControl & ".Backcolor = " & Str(lngColor)`

`Rs!NameofControl`  is from a record.  `lngColor` is calculated from a hex color string from the same record.

If I take what the string evaluates to and execute it in the immediate window, it works fine. Typically it is something like:

```
Forms!Main.bxBEStep1.Backcolor =  123456 'object is a box as a background
```

-or-

```
Forms!Main.SUB_Visits.Form.Section(0).Backcolor =  123456 '0 is the detail section
```

Currently it evaluates to 0 (False).  Not surprising because of the equal sign. But more so,  it seems that I need to somehow specify that the result of the function should be defined as  executable code and to execute it.

I’m guessing that maybe it should be of the form:

```
Public Function UpdateControlBackground(Frobnitz as String) As ???
```

But I don’t know what the ??? should be.  I’ve tried various items in the list suggested, but none have worked. Any and all suggestions welcome.

Comment: Thank you to the editor for making this more readable.